# Perfmon on windows 10 - no "process counter"

Tags: windows-10, performance-monitor

i want to use the performance monitor to monitor resource usage for a specific program.

So i tried adding a counter but i could only find global counters there.

I tried creating a user defined data collector set but same counters.

As i understand it there should be a "process" counter like the one showed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122749/how-to-log-memory-consumption-of-a-windows-process-with-perfmon

but it is not there... any ideas?

Edit: here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzUUI.jpg

Comment: Counters for a specific process won't exist until the program is actually running. Is the program you're trying to monitor already running?

Comment: yes, but its not the program that is missing. it's the whole process counter ( even if my program isn't running lots of other are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open Performance Monitor, right-click on the graph and select **Add Counter**.

The following dialog box appears:
[image]

First, please notice that there is a Process *category*. (The Stack Overflow question to which you had linked didn't show the category in its screenshot. But mine is showing it. It is at the top of the list in the screenshot and is blue.) You need to expand it and select **% Processor Time**.

Please be careful: You need the **Process** category, not *Processor* and not anything else!

Then, from the bottom pane, you need to select your process.

### They are missing

Are your performance counters missing? It is possible to rebuild them using the following:

1. The [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pctn1cAS5m2nu0DfVCKO3e9YZX9tEvQx) Registry key, which is large
2. The [`perfc009.dat` and `perfh009.dat` files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19MGE8cpnTvAgXEa6Cdq4rs0GQzn41S7U), which go into your `system32` folder.

I have collected these from a copy of Windows 10 Version 1709 x64. But anyone else can always collect them from a fresh copy of the appropriate version and edition of Windows 10. Simply, install one on a virtual machine. You don't even need to activate it.

To copy these item to their correct places (Windows Registry and `system32` folder), you need to start Windows in safe mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but just for posterity. I have no process category! https://imgur.com/FbfQMjt

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Windows server 2012, and [this post](https://hen.co.za/blog/2016/02/the-case-of-the-missing-process-performance-counter/) helped me to fix it